# Handle / access files on the disk

Tags: java, file-management, file-manipulation

I'm using Java with JSF an Glassfish 3 container.
In my web application I'm trying to implement a file(image) management system.

I have a `config.properties` file from where I read the path where the uploaded images should be saved.

```
save.file.path.event = D:\\upload
```

The file upload works and all the files are in their place but when I try to list the image the browser says that no image could be found.

```
<img src = "D:/upload/img1.png" />
```

The web server is in a totally different partition.

Besides the *no image found* problem I have the following question regarding good practices in this area: If their will be a time when I will publish the application on a web server how safe / correct is to use a path like `D:\\upload`? Some issues which come to my mind are the differences between operating systems or the uncertainty of a partition name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are two ways to solve this problem

**1. Place the files in the Application**

If the application name is `MyApplication`, you can specify a path like `MyApplication/uploads/ images` and the files will be saved inside the actual application. The downside of this method is that at every redeploy or hotdeploy the files will be deleted.

**2. Place an absolute path in the web container config**

For *Tomcat* go to: `../ Apache Tomcat x.x.xx/conf/server.xml` and there write:

```
<Context path="/web_uploads" docBase="C:/uploads/"/>
```

For *Glassfish* go to: `sun-web.xml` file and write:

```
<sun-web-app>
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=C:"/>
</sun-web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to reference the image with a local path. Keep in mind that the web browser (on the client machine) is interpreting that img tag, so it's going to look at that location on it's own file system rather than the server's file system. You need to make the link point to the web address that your server is serving the image up at. For example `http://server/upload/img1.png`.

Comment: Thanks! But then how should the upload path should look like? I don't think that something like `D:\\upload` is the best way to do it.

Comment: Put it anywhere you want on the local file system, as long as the web server it serving up that folder to the "web."

Comment: And how can I do that? Isn't there also the possibility to place the upload folder in the application and just offer a relative path to the folder